# MySQL Dense_Rank() and Max() functions not working in the same statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I started with this MySQL query which worked fine:

```
select 
h.id,
h.name,
count(distinct c.sales_id)
from customers h join sales c on h.id=c.id
group by 1,2
order by 3 desc, 2 desc
```

However, now I want to add 2 additional columns in the same statement:

1. The first column should be the max value from the 'count(distinct c.sales_id)' column --> `max(count(distinct c.sales_id))`
2. The second column should add a dense_rank by the 'count(distinct c.sales_id)' column --> `dense_rank() over (order by count(distinct c.sales_id))`

I have a hard time adding these two columns as I keep getting an aggregation error with this query:

```
select 
h.id,
h.name,
count(distinct c.sales_id),
max(count(distinct c.sales_id)),
dense_rank() over (order by count(distinct c.sales_id))
from customers h join sales c on h.id=c.id
group by 1,2
order by 3 desc, 2 desc
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be very close to a solution.

In SQL, one can't max a count.
But one can max OVER a count.

So this should work in MySql 8.0

(untested on sample data)

```
select 
h.id,
h.name,
count(distinct c.sales_id) as total_uniq_sales,
MAX(count(distinct c.sales_id)) OVER (),
dense_rank() over (order by count(distinct c.sales_id))
from customers h 
join sales c on h.id=c.id
group by h.id, h.name
order by total_uniq_sales desc, h.name desc
```

The reason behind that is that the window functions are processed after the aggregation functions.

Comment: Thank you so much but when I run the query with your approach, I still get an error: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(),
dense_rank() over (order by count(distinct c. sales_id))   
from customers ' at line 5

Comment: what version of MySql are you using.  Well, I didn't test it on data yet. So I could be wrong here.

Comment: I am using the code editor on Hackerrank for SQL challenges. I am not sure which version it is.

Comment: don't know that. can it run a statement like `select @@version;` ?

Comment: Interesting, it states: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: To bad.  Window functions were only added with the 8.0 version.

Comment: Anyway, check out this [test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=094bb3703b7baabbd96e4b2a14f59a53)  It would work on a mysql 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204160/discussion-between-cocoo84hh-and-lukstorms).